# how to fetch only specific data from graphql query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, prismic.io

I am trying to fetch some data from my CMS but I am facinf an error when fetching a specific data.
It's an array that I want to fetch with the graphql query :

```
{
allPrismicLastPosts {
    nodes {
      data {
        links {
          blog {
            document {
              ... on PrismicBlog {
                data {
                  post_img {
                    url
                  }
                  post_title {
                    text
                  }
                  post_paragraph {
                    text
                  }
                  tag
                }
              }
              ... on PrismicCulture {
                data {
                  tag
                  culture_image {
                    url
                  }
                  culture_paragraph {
                    text
                  }
                  culture_title {
                    text
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is it JSON Format :

```
            "links": [
              {
                "blog": {
                  "document": {
                    "data": {
                      "post_img": {
                        "url": "https://images.prismic.io/zinee/67254822-5c44-42fe-8d5b-7f500141c3a7_Mask%20Group%20(1).png?ixlib=gatsbyFP&auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=max"
                      },
                      "post_title": {
                        "text": "Make more time for the work that matters most using our services"
                      },
                      "post_paragraph": {
                        "text": "A lot of different components that will help you create the perfect look"
                      },
                      "tag": "Fiction"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "blog": {
                  "document": {
                    "data": {
                      "post_img": {
                        "url": "https://images.prismic.io/zinee/4898e2a8-ebfb-41d4-b843-550e9d9c84da_Mask%20Group.png?ixlib=gatsbyFP&auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=max"
                      },
                      "post_title": {
                        "text": "Make myspace your best designed space"
                      },
                      "post_paragraph": {
                        "text": "A lot of different components that will help you create the perfect look"
                      },
                      "tag": "Fiction"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "blog": {
                  "document": {
                    "data": {
                      "post_img": {
                        "url": "https://images.prismic.io/zinee/67254822-5c44-42fe-8d5b-7f500141c3a7_Mask%20Group%20(1).png?ixlib=gatsbyFP&auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=max"
                      },
                      "post_title": {
                        "text": "Make more time for the work that matters most using our services"
                      },
                      "post_paragraph": {
                        "text": "A lot of different components that will help you create the perfect look"
                      },
                      "tag": "Fiction"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "blog": {
                  "document": {
                    "data": {
                      "post_img": {
                        "url": "https://images.prismic.io/zinee/4898e2a8-ebfb-41d4-b843-550e9d9c84da_Mask%20Group.png?ixlib=gatsbyFP&auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=max"
                      },
                      "post_title": {
                        "text": "Make myspace your best designed space"
                      },
                      "post_paragraph": {
                        "text": "A lot of different components that will help you create the perfect look"
                      },
                      "tag": "Fiction"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
```

I get a `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')` error when I fetch it like this :

```
{post.data.links.map((test)=>
      (
        <>
          <h1>{test.blog.document.data.post_paragraph.text}</h1>
        </>
      ))}
```

But when I try to fetch like this  it works:

```
{post.data.links.map((test)=>
      (
        <>
          <h1>{test.blog.document.data.tag}</h1>
        </>
      ))}
```

Any idea how to fix this please ?
the `tag` field works and get fetched perfectly but with data like : `post_paragraph.text` or `title.text` doesn't work !!

Comment: PrismicBlog has post_paragraph, but PrismicCulture has culture_paragraph that's why it is undefined.

Comment: yes indeed , but I mapped these link like this : `{post.data.links.map((test)` so it should show `post_paragraph` for PrismicBlog and PrismicCulture accordingly right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GraphQL fragment `PrismicBlog` has `post_paragraph` which has `text` (so your loop works) however, when it's mapping `PrismicCulture` fragment, where the structure differs, your map breaks because there's no such property, in `PrismicCulture` it's called `culture_paragraph` with a `text` property in it.

If you are trying to map both fragments in one loop I'd suggest using the same data structure  in the CMS, changing `culture_paragraph` for `post_paragraph` so your loop will be valid.

If that's not an option, you can use GraphQL alias to map your `culture_paragraph` into `post_paragraph` such as:

```
{
allPrismicLastPosts {
    nodes {
      data {
        links {
          blog {
            document {
              ... on PrismicBlog {
                data {
                  post_img {
                    url
                  }
                  post_title {
                    text
                  }
                  post_paragraph {
                    text
                  }
                  tag
                }
              }
              ... on PrismicCulture {
                data {
                  tag
                  culture_image {
                    url
                  }
                  post_paragraph: culture_paragraph {
                    text
                  }
                  culture_title {
                    text
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `post_paragraph: culture_paragraph` alias.

Another alternative is using the optional chaining to only print the text if the structure matches the loop:

```
{post.data.links.map((test)=>
      (
        <>
          <h1>{test.blog.document?.data?.post_paragraph?.text}</h1>
        </>
      ))}
```

Comment: I need 15 reputation to upvote this ! I will remember to do it later !